# Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement a login functionality by following https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-persist-a-logged-in-user-in-react/ blog.

I want to persist the user token in local storage.

Everything is working fine, but every time I refresh the page, it throws me an error:

> Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have
> access to the actual error object in development.

I have read to fix it clear the site data here [Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611310/uncaught-error-a-cross-origin-error-was-thrown-react-doesnt-have-access-to-th).

But, I want to have a proper solution or any alternate method to bypass it.

So, that even on the local machine, I can use the login functionality.

Here is what I have tried so far:

For checking if the current user is signed in or not:

```
const [userState, setUserState] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (loggedInUser) {
      const foundUser = JSON.parse(loggedInUser);
      console.log(foundUser);
      setUserState(foundUser);
    }
  }, []);
```

For login:

```
const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = { username, password };

    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/",
      user
    )

    props.setUserState(response.data)
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("user");

    if (!loggedInUser) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', response.data)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem. It is a security feature to prevent sites from stealing sensitive data from you. Imagine you loading [www.learningjavascript.com](http://www.learningjavascript.com), and a malicious attempt is made to myEvilHacker.com without your knowledge, and sending your banking information from when you paid your bills on [www.chase.com](http://www.chase.com). It's a pain, but necessary.

The problem is that you are trying to load a resource from another origin; for example:

1. You are on [www.myawesomesite.com](http://www.myawesomesite.com)
2. You try and load something from [www.anothersite.com](http://www.anothersite.com)

^^^ You are "crossing origins" here. Sorry Bro, can't do that.

Typically to get around this you must:

1. Allow cross-origin requests on the server-side by enabling CORS. Depending on your web server, there there is some setting allow cross-origin requests.
2. Move the data onto the same origin. In the above example, put everything on [www.myawesomesite.com](http://www.myawesomesite.com)

Also beware that more recent versions of Chrome will view requests to `localhost` as cross-origin, and block them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed explanation.
But I have allowed cross-origin requests on my server-side.
Everything is working fine until I refresh the page.

For more context about this local storage problem please refer this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611310/uncaught-error-a-cross-origin-error-was-thrown-react-doesnt-have-access-to-th

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message on this snippet from my code:

```
prevItem.products = JSON.parse(orders[index].orderItems).
```

But my variable was ALREADY json. After I removed the parse method, everything was fine.