# Stripe.js PaymentElement throws Cross-Origin error in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, cross-domain

Trying to incorporate Strips.js into my React App (TrendEdge.app)

Am following their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react)  word for word.

Have wrapped my app in Elements tag, correctly declared Options constant, and the StripePromise.

As soon as their PaymentElement is rendered via my checkout Dialog, the app crashes and throws this error...

*Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development*

... I went to this [React Cross Origin Errors](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/cross-origin-errors.html) page, but was unable to find my solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There is not enough information to effectively help debug this. I'd look at this SO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48611310/uncaught-error-a-cross-origin-error-was-thrown-react-doesnt-have-access-to-th thread that has extensive debugging steps first. Then, if none of these help, you'd want to share your code here.